# SSH connection refused on Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu

I installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04 on a 16 GB microSD card and am trying to setup headlessly. I'm trying to SSH into the Pi. I am able to ping the Pi. I added an empty file "ssh" to the boot partition but connection is still being refused. nmap shows all ports down. Unfortunately since I don't have a monitor I have to do it headlessly.

Comment: Okay never mind I found that the first boot requires monitor since it won't be able to enable SSH service until user account etc is set up

Comment: This seems to be a special need of Ubuntu MATE 16.04. With Raspbian you don't need a monitor for first boot. Please can you make your comment an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you cannot setup `Ubuntu MATE` without a keyboard/monitor - BECAUSE you need to create a user account, there seems little point.